# Defining class properties in headers

Tags: objective-c, properties, header-files

Please can somebody explain the difference to me between the following two syntaxes:

```
@interface BCScanner : CDVPlugin <BCScannerDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *buttonCallback;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* childView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton*  imageButton;

- (void)createView;

@end
```

vs.

```
@interface BCScanner : CDVPlugin <BCScannerDelegate> {
    NSString *buttonCallback;
    UIView* childView;
    UIButton*  imageButton;
}

- (void)createView;

@end
```

Do they both do the same thing?

Comment: Do you know what they are, at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code:

```
@interface BCScanner : CDVPlugin <BCScannerDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *buttonCallback;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* childView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton*  imageButton;

- (void)createView;

@end
```

defines a class with 3 public properties. These public properties can be used by any other class, including the `BSScanner` class itself. This is the proper way to define properties that you want other classes to have access to.

The other block of code:

```
@interface BCScanner : CDVPlugin <BCScannerDelegate> {
    NSString *buttonCallback;
    UIView* childView;
    UIButton*  imageButton;
}

- (void)createView;

@end
```

defines no properties. Instead it is declaring three private instance variables. These variables can only be accessed by instances of the `BCScanner` class. Other class have no direct access to the variables. There is no reason to declare private instance variables in the public header file. These should be moved to the private class extension in the .m file.

Whether you declare public properties or private ivars depends on the need of the values. If other classes should be able to access the values, then declare the public properties in the .h file. If no other class should have access, then declare private ivars in the .m file, not the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are just setters and getters.

For more info check-

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/should-i-use-a-property-or-an-instance-variable/

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices to define variables.

```
@interface BCScanner : CDVPlugin <BCScannerDelegate> {
     UIButton*  imageButton;
}
```

In this case you can access to variable wihout your class.

```
[imageButton setTitle:.... ];
```

However, this variable is private. 
To access to this variable you must writte getter, or setter to set value.

If define variable with @property, you can access to variable with class:

```
self.imageButton
```

or you can use setter from another class:

```
[AnotherClassVariable setImageButton:(UIButton *)];
```

In this case is automaticaly declares the accessor and mutator methods for this variable (with @synthesize).

Practical use can be like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueId"]){
        MyClassWithProperty *dc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dc.imageButton = self.imageButton;
        //[dc setImageButton:self.imageButton];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - so they do the same thing essentially, they just define different scopes?

Comment: @keldar No, the two sets of code in your question do two completely different things. They are not the same thing at all.

Comment: Some of the comments in this answer are misleading. Not all properties can be used from other classes. And there are more than two choices to define variables.

Comment: @rmaddy could you provide an answer as to the differences to clarify please?